# Texture mirror in paint mode

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, mirror

i'm wondering is it posible to mirror texture in paint mode after i apply mirror modifier and unwrap uv's, like symmetries model in sculpt mode but in paint with texture? Also i have turned on X Mirror and Topology Mirror in Options i'm wondering is there any option after i select one side to "one click" select mirrored side as well?

Note: For both questions Mirror Modifier are applied and model is already unvwraped.

Answer (score 3):

You can paint in Texture Paint mode and toggle symmetry in the Symmetry panel for X, Y and Z axis.
[image]
If you want to just mirror the texture, you can delete one half of the model and use a mirror modifier, unwrap the mesh to align with your intended texture and then apply the mirror modifier to get the mesh UVs to align on both sides.

edit: To use the mirror modifier to align both sides to a single side of paint image, I first delete and add a mirror modifier.[image: 1 mirror] I unwrap and arrange my UVs to get the most pixels in the image bounds.[image: 2 unwrap] I set a new image with a grid to check the density and see if it is even, also still looking for stretching.[image: 3 stretch] I apply the mirror and set up a new image at the resolution I want to paint from the Slots tab in the texture toolbar.[image: 4 apply mirror] The painting then is all mirrored across the x axis here.[image: 5 painted mirror]

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you please explain how to unwrap mesh with my intended texture? Thank you very much!

Comment: I will try to update the post later on tonight when I get home.