# There's still symmetry even though I've turned it off? (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osx

I'm new to blender and trying to make a simple face I have disabled symmetry but whenever I try to texture paint its always still symmetrical. I have looked for other answers but nothing helps me.
I am using a mac.
Thank you!

[image: symmetrys off]

Comment: the UVs of your model might overlap symmetrically, effectively applying the texture you're painting on both sides. In this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91282/texture-mirror-in-paint-mode/91500#91500 the OP asks for the opposite thing, the solution might show  what's wrong with yours.

Comment: check if your mesh still has an active mirror modifier. Apply the modifier and unwrap your mesh to be able to paint on both sides independently.

Comment: Yes! It worked! I just have to paint everything in the UV editor.