# Avoid Texture Symmetry on complex Uv maps

Tags: uv, texture-painting

In Blender2.79, texture paint is showing **symmetry** even after activating these settings-

Mirror modifier - **Applied**
Texture Symmetry = **Off**
Sculpt Symmetry = **Off**

One explanation can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111206/theres-still-symmetry-even-though-ive-turned-it-off-cycles#comments-111206) `UVs overlap causing texture symmetry`

However,in this case there is clearly  **no Uv overlap** as seen in the video below .
How to avoid texture symmetry on complex Uv maps?

[image]

Comment: Recheck your islands - you don't have independent islands for right side/left side of X axis, so you will still see symmetry happen when painting. To check, turn on Face Selection Masking and dab again on a selected face - you will still see paint on both sides because you seem to have an UV unwrap from before applying the mirror modifier. Try setting up a new UV layer in the Properties tab, make it active, unwrap the whole mesh again using Smart UV Projection and try painting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventhough the **Mirror modifier** was applied ,**it was applied after the Uv's were unwrapped** causing Symmetry (even if the Texture paint symmetry options were off).Applying the mirror modifier and unwrapping Uv's after, solved the issue.

Thanks to @Craig D Jones for pointing it out.