# How can I make a 1 side UV texture?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, materials, uv

**Hey guys!**

Today I'm here with another question, since I finally fixed my last Blender problem ^^

(I'm still using 2.79, but I'll move to 2.8 soon, when I get used to it)

*The question is:*

**How can I make a 1 side UV map texture, that auto reflects any edit on the other side?**

*Example...*

I already made a anime face, but when I unwrap it, it looks like a 2D paper, showing both sides of the face... as normal.

If I add a design, such as freckles, blush, or tattoos to only the right side of the UV texture... obviously, it's not reflecting on the left side, since I just edited the right side.

**So, I want to make a UV mapping like the reference pictures below...**
[image]
[image]

U can see that in the reference pictures, it only shows the Right/1 side of the face, and if I make a deco on it, it auto reflects on the other side perfectly symmetrical.

**Also, every part of the face is edited on just 1 side, and reflected to the other side symmetrically, like the eyes, eyebrows, lashes, mouth, etc...**
[image]

**It only needs 1 side of the UV to perfectly texture the whole face, like when you take a piece of paper, and fold it in the middle.**

I've already been looking for days for a lot of UV/Texture tutorials on YT and Google, typing all keywords possible, but I can't find a clue...

None of the tutorials and manuals I checked, explain nor show a way to achieve this.

**If you guys can please explain me how to do this, or send me some links to useful tutorials explaining this, It'll be really appreciated ^^**

*Thank you all for your help, I will be waiting for your answers!*

**See u later guys ^^**

Comment: Here you'll find an answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91282/texture-mirror-in-paint-mode but I can't find any symmetry in 2.79, it must be possible with some addons. But you can use the other trick he gives: Delete half of your object, give it a Mirror modifier, unwrap correctly one part and it will symmetrize on the other side. Apply your modifier.

Comment: @moonboots. Thank u so much! I'll try it right away ^^